# After almost 6 months, why google is still indexing my old site?

Tags: google, redirects, search-engine-indexing, multiple-domains, url-removal

I purchased a domain [steakovercooked.com](https://steakovercooked.com)  to replace the domain zhihua-lai.com  in Jan 2016.

I do a 301 redirect in zhihua-lai.com/.htacess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^zhihua-lai.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.zhihua-lai.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://steakovercooked.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
Header set Connection keep-alive
```

There is no robots.txt under old domain zhihua-lai.com

In Google Web Master, I have requested a domain change:

[image: Change of Address at Google Webmaster]

But after 6 months, google still indexes zhihua-lai.com

[image: Google still indexes zhihua-lai.com]

Any explanations?

Comment: You have a problem redirecting to your new domain. Using Chrome, I get: This site can’t provide a secure connection steakovercooked.com uses an unsupported protocol. ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH - The client and server don't support a common SSL protocol version or cipher suite. This is likely to be caused when the server needs RC4, which is no longer considered secure.

Comment: I am using Chrome and I didn't see any problems

Comment: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=steakovercooked.com&latest

Comment: Just letting you know. You may want to look at this further. If I cannot get to your site, others cannot either. Not sure the reason, I was just sending you some ProWebmaster Love! Cheers!!

Comment: Hi @closetnoc   I am using CloudFlare Universal SSL,  so here is the list of browsers that are supported.  https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/203041594-What-browsers-work-with-CloudFlare-s-SSL-certificates-

Comment: @closetnoc Do you happen to be on on XP trying to visit it? The only thing on XP that will work with CF free plan SSL's (due to EECDH) is Firefox, else you will see that error. Chrome is at a "do not fix" state on XP.

Comment: @dhaupin Yes. Chrome is up to date though it is about to end. It was supposed to be Vista, but then MS recalled Vista and gave me XP instead and then wanted to charge me for Vista. I bought and paid for Vista! It is on the receipt. It apparently does not matter. I refuse to give MS anymore $ after that. I am a linux guy, however, some things I use only run on Windows. Bummer!

Comment: @dhaupin ah yeah I hear ya...classic MS. Linux here too. Firefox should work though.

Comment: @dhaupin I have my mothers computer. She cannot use it anymore. In fact, she locked it out doing a Windows 8.1 install. I do not have a rebuild CD for my HP mini or for Mom's computer. Each is about $45 with only XP available for the HP Mini and Windows 8, 8.1, and 10 for mom's laptop. I hesitate paying for the CD's, however, I thought I might get the Windows 10 for Mom's computer. I cannot stand the tile cr@p. I prefer the classic GUI. I am a coder afterall! Which would you chose? I am thinking Windows 10 or linux. Or should I just live with 8.1?

Comment: @dhaupin BTW- I am impressed that you pinged the issue! XP is still about 10% of all Windows installs according one site I saw.

Comment: @closetnoc Well, i would fresh install 8 then do the upgrade to 10 if you want the freebee. It really is better than 8.x, although it's very un-nerving how much "telemetry" and cram-it-in-your-throat-bloat they throw out. I think the free upgrade to 10 ends July 29. I did it, saved the Windows key, then promptly wiped it from the puter to allocate all to mint (or whatever). I figured i can virtualize 10 on there if i need it. Depends on what you wanna do though i suppose and how comfortable you feel about phoning home constantly.

Comment: @dhaupin I wondered why Windows 10 for the computer was available! Now I know. I might pony up the $45 for Windows 10 in case linux ends up not being best. I wish I had the original Windows 8 CD, but it did not come with one. How cheap is that?? Cheers!

Comment: FWIW you are probably only finding these pages because you are doing a `site:` search. A `site:` search does return pages that would not ordinarily be returned in a _normal_ search. For example, search for a unique phrase that occurs on one of the pages in the SERPs above (eg. "Dr Zhihua Lai Offers private tutoring at Cambridgeshire"), without the `site:` search, the page from your old domain is _not_ returned, but the corresponding page on the new domain is.

Comment: but shouldn't google drop all pages of the old domain?